# Cassandra:Request did not complete within rpc_timeout

Tags: database, exception, cassandra, rpc

i was working with Cassandra 1.2.4 probably, after restoring some key-space when i tried to query in a key-space it gave me `Request did not complete within rpc_timeout`

so i checked `system.log & output.log` under `/var/log/cassandra` path

i just find this exception:

> Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:42,5,main]
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: java.io.EOFException

what is the reason ? and how can i get rid of `rpc_timeout`

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Seems somehow your SStables are corrupted. You can try rebuilding them using nodetool's 
`scrub [keyspace]` operation.

If you can't access a specific keyspace,

```
> ./nodetool -u <username> -pw <password> -h <cassandra_ip> scrub <keyspace>
```

or if you can't access any keyspace,

```
> ./nodetool -u <username> -pw <password> -h <cassandra_ip> scrub
```

Comment: thanks @Bhathiya , but it give me this exception `Exception in thread "main" FSWriteError in /var/lib/cassandra/data/key_space/table_name/snapshots/pre-scrub-1391324805458/key_space-table_name-ic-10-Statistics.db`

Comment: That is a file system permission issue. Give r/w permissions to cassandra directory in /var/lib/

Answer (score 1):

`cqlsh` returns `rpc_timeout` when any error occur in server. (remote procedure call -to server- timed out).

i think you problem was after a backup/restore and the restoring step may not perform correctly and your sstables corrupted. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968374/cassandra-snapshot-unable-to-create-hard-link-from-errno-1/) may be helpful.