# cassandra snapshot : Unable to create hard link from errno 1

Tags: cassandra, errno

i'm using cassandra 1.2.8 in ubuntu 12.4.

i used snapshot command already and backing up process was ok!

but now when i use this command i get error like below:

```
   Exception in thread "main" FSWriteError in /var/lib/cassandra/data/english/word_doc  /snapshots/1393155090911/english-word_doc-ic-10-Index.db
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:80)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.createLinks(SSTableReader.java:1063)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshotWithoutFlush(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1566)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.snapshot(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1611)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.snapshot(Table.java:194)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.takeSnapshot(StorageService.java:2205)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:74)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:277)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:226)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:253)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:856)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:805)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1476)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:98)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1317)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1409)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:839)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create hard link from /var/lib/cassandra/data/english/word_doc/english-word_doc-ic-10-Index.db to /var/lib/cassandra/data/english/word_doc/snapshots/1393155090911/english-word_doc-ic-10-Index.db (errno 1)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.CLibrary.createHardLink(CLibrary.java:174)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:76)
... 40 more
```

note: my current data base is a back up version that i restore in my cassandra!

thanks for your help :)

edit: i have two keyspace,A and B. B is a back up version that i restore and store more data on it, but A is not. i can create back up from A with out any problem,but for B i get above error!

Comment: Are the source and destination files on the same partition?

Comment: yes,there is only one node

Comment: Can you try running this command as the user that Cassandra runs as, and seeing if there is an error? `ln /var/lib/cassandra/data/english/word_doc/english-word_doc-ic-10-Index.db /var/lib/cassandra/data/english/word_doc/snapshots/1393155090911/english-word_doc-ic-10-Index.db`

Comment: @psanford meant if they were on the same [FS partition](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html#sect_03_01_02). However, since disabling hardlink access protection solved your problem, it seems this is a matter of file ownership, not of partitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this seems to be an ubuntu 12.04 security issue on hard-links.

use this command to disable that:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.yama.protected_nonaccess_hardlinks=0
```

and after restore, reset it to its original value:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.yama.protected_nonaccess_hardlinks=1
```

Comment: Just in case, remember to restore this setting after taking your snapshot: `sudo sysctl -w kernel.yama.protected_nonaccess_hardlinks=1`

Comment: This is probably not the real solution. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25174635/442724) I just added.

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this issue again I found that I had a few root-owned files inside `/var/lib/cassandra/data/.../etcetera`, which triggered the hard link access restriction.

Recursively `chown`ing all directories and files inside `/var/lib/cassandra/data` solved the problem.

Comment: are you using ubuntu 12.04? I tested what you say before but did not works for me...

Comment: @طاهر I had this issue in both Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, the root cause in both cases being the existence of files owned not by user cassandra (under which snapshots take place), but by root (or any other for that matter), which precludes hardlinking with the new kernel security rules. If you don't have any non-cassandra files in your data directory, then my fix won't make any difference for you.