# createHardLink error when run cassandra repair

Tags: cassandra

I'm running cassandra 3.11.3 in three nodes with linux el7.
The repair process always succeeded before untill it got problem recently and  never recovered.
I finally find it is because there is a failure in one  of the 3 nodes during cassandra repair, in that server log, it tell

```
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/db/data/data/wiotp/device_mementos-53b0fe
10e2bf11e98af1457e3e7c4184/snapshots/b0b3e1e0-6a78-11ea-9eca-33d64338b8d7/mc-186-big-Statistics.db -> /var/db/data/data
/wiotp/device_mementos-53b0fe10e2bf11e98af1457e3e7c4184/mc-186-big-Statistics.db: Input/output error
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.createHardLink(FileUtils.java:103) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11
.3]
```

**investigation done so far:**

I checked the access permission, no issue, all folders  and sub-folder looks like this

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 cassandra
```

I verified the destination file, it existed

```
$  ls /var/db/data/data/wiotp/device_mementos-53b0fe10e2bf11e98af1457e3e7c4184/mc-186-big-Statistics.db -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 cassandra 2033 4780 Feb 15 01:31 /var/db/data/data/wiotp/device_mementos-53b0fe10e2bf11e98af1457e3e7c4184/mc-186-big-Statistics.db
```

I manually created the hard link file, it can not be created successfully. 
but a question here is only if I firstly created the sub-folder `b0b3e1e0-6a78-11ea-9eca-33d64338b8d7` under the folder  `snapshot` then this hard link file can be created, or it will failed as `No such file or directory`.
another thing is, under the folder `snapshot`, other sub-folder's name is a  numeric string, like `1581814812868` except the above one which seems very different.

I check the related code, and find it should run into `Files.createLink(to.toPath(), from.toPath());` as this code clip show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QZzG.png)

but still not sure what the error `Input/output error` really complain about.

I searched similar case here, seems this [cassandra snapshot : Unable to create hard link from errno 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968374/cassandra-snapshot-unable-to-create-hard-link-from-errno-1) is closest to my error, but unfortunately the solution there doesn't work for me.

Dose anyone has any idea? thank you!

Comment: Yikes @ 3.11.3.  That release had some major problems, so we skipped it all together.  Probably not related to this issue, but I'd recommend upgrading to the latest patch level (3.11.6).

Comment: thanks!  Aaron.   As I am in a live Env,  upgrading would be my last choice, it is better if there is other  quick fix.